# Make Apache wait longer before delivering HTTP 408 request timeout

Tags: php, apache, configuration, cgi, fastcgi

My configuration:
Apache 2.2.4
PHP 5.2.4 (fastCGI)
Windows XP pro

I have a script that takes more than a minute to run but after exactly 60 seconds (proven by Fiddler) the server always delivers a 408 timeout.  My PHP max execution time is set to 120 seconds.  After doing some reading I've tried putting a "Timeout 120" directive in my Apache config file though I'm not confident that directive relates to what I'm trying to do.  No dice.  Is there any way to make apache wait longer before returning the 408?  (Yes, I've restarted the web server between making config changes).  Many thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the -appConnTimeout parameter in the [FastCgiServer directive](http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiServer).

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.  Though I ended up fixing it a different way, I'm pretty sure your solution would have fixed it for me and it was your suggestion that put me on the right path.  In my external FastCGI config file I found the following directive:  
Server type="application/x-httpd-php" CommandLine="C:\Program Files\Zend\Core\bin\php-cgi.exe" ConnectionTimeout="30" RequestTimeout="60" ... (it continues but I've truncated it)  

I bumped up the RequestTimeout to 120 and it's fixed!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure which one of these lines solves the problem; probalby the execution time - but it solved my 408 problems (added to settings.php):

```
    $conf['drupal_http_request_fails'] = FALSE;

    ini_set('max_execution_time',       '600');
    ini_set('memory_limit',             '512M');
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize',      '128M');
    ini_set('post_max_size',            '128M');
    ini_set('query_cache_size',         '128M');
```